# Prove that a function is convex by only using positive semi-definiteness

Tags: general-topology, multivariable-calculus, convex-analysis, partial-derivative, convex-optimization

let $x \in \mathbb{R}^n$ where $f(x) = (1 + ||x||^2)^{1/2}$. Prove that it is convex. As of right now, we define a convex function to be a function with a positive semi definite second derivative. So how do I prove that the second derivative of this function is positive semi definite?

I tried to use Taylors theorem where

$f(a+h) = f(a) + f'(a)*h + R(t), t \in (0, 1)$
I'm trying to figure out a way to prove that the remainder is always non negative.

Comment: How have you defined convexity of a function?

Comment: This doesn't use the Hessian, but $ f$ is closely related to the $2$-norm on $\mathbb R^{n+1}$. I think the convexity of $ f $ can be proved using the convexity of the $2$-norm.

Comment: A function is convex if the hessian matrix is positive semi definite.

Comment: If I recall corectly, a function $f$ is convex, when $f(t \cdot x + (1-t) \cdot y) \leq t \cdot  f(x) + (1-t) \cdot  f(y)$ holds for $x,y \in \R^n$ and $t \in (0,1)$. I think it is rather simple to show this directly for arbitrary $x,y \in \R^n$, using as littleO suggested, the convexity of the $2$-norrm.

Comment: what is a 2-norm? I haven't heard of this term before

Comment: It is also known as the Euclidean-Norm, see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Norm_(mathematics)#Euclidean_norm)

Comment: The 2-norm of $x$ is $\|x\|$.

Comment: is it possible to show that the hessian matrix is positive semi-definite instead? We are not using the usual definition of convex yet...

Comment: Have you actually TRIED calculating the second derivative?

Comment: I did the partial derivative and it is very complicated and ugly, unless I'm doing it wrong

Answer (score 3):

Just compute the second derivative, we have, by the chain rule
$$\def\norm#1{\left|#1\right|} Df(x)h = \frac 1{(1 + \norm{x}^2)^{1/2}} \cdot \def\<#1>{\left<#1\right>}\<x, h> $$
Hence, 
$$ D^2f(x)[h,k] = -\frac 1{(1 + \norm x^2)^{3/2}}\<x,h>\<x,k> + \frac{1}{(1 + \norm x^2)^{1/2}}\<h,k> $$
So, we have
\begin{align*}
  D^2 f(x)[h,h] &= - \frac 1{\def\op{(1 + \norm x^2)}\op^{3/2}}\<x,h>^2 + \frac{\op}{\op^{3/2}}\norm h^2\\
   &= \frac{\norm h^2 + \norm h^2\norm x^2 - \<x,h>^2}{\op^{3/2}}\\
   &\ge \frac{\norm h^2}{\op^{3/2}} \qquad\text{by Cauchy-Schwarz}
\end{align*}
So $D^2 f(x)$ is positive definite.